# iOS asynchronous chat

Tags: ios, asynchronous

I am writing an iPhone app that needs to have a "chat" function.  Users will post messages to a wall.

I desire the functionality that, when users post to the wall, another user (on a different device) will see the message with minimal latency.

I can do this by querying the server every so often, but I would prefer to do things asynchronously.

How do I send asynchronous messages to a device when a new message has been posted?

Comment: you can begin from here http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12 (it's a 2 parts tutorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know how much experience you have with developing for iOS platform... [XMPPFramework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) this is a great open source framework that does exactly what you want.. CHAT! Here is a [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/)...